# Subshell IO redirection

Tags: bash, redirect, file-descriptor, subshell

Given a file `"foo.txt"`, created from:

```
$ seq 1 10 > "foo.txt"
```

I'm trying to read both the first and last line of the file, and I started by redirecting the file to a subshell, so that the list of commands will consume the file in sequence -- each command consumes the input from the point the last command has left it, **I suppose**:

```
$ (head -1; tail -1) < "foo.txt"
1
10
```

However, if I try the same with a *temporary* file descriptor, the output is not the same:

```
$ (head -1; tail -1) < <(seq 1 10)
1
```

**Questions**:

1. I'm not sure of what to name `<(seq 1 10)`, but what is the difference between this *temporary* file descriptor and a *regular* one (`"foo.txt"`), that causes the subshell execution to behave differently?
2. How can I achieve the same behavior of redirecting a `"foo.txt"` to the subshell, but without a *temporary* file -- without actually creating a file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's just a buffering issue.  Try:

```
cat foo.txt | ( head -1; tail -1)
```

and you will (probably) see the same thing (head consumes the entire input).   Probably what is happening is that head is behaving differently with a regular file than with a pipe, and the process substitution (which is the name for the `<(cmd)` syntax) is creating a pipe.  (In Linux, the `head` from Gnu coreutils does an `lseek` to try to reposition at the final newline that it outputs, but the `lseek` fails on a pipe.)

Also try:

```
(head -1; tail -1) < <(cat /usr/share/dict/words)
```

Here, `head` only consumes the first page of input, and tail sees the final line of the data.

The behavior you are seeing is not well defined, since there is no standard that dictates how much of the data head is allowed to consume.  If you replace `head` with `sh -c 'read line; echo "$line"'`, then you will get the desired behavior in all cases.  (Or write your own tool to provide the behavior of `head` that you want -- printing a fixed number of lines while not consuming any more than that.)

Comment: +1 for very good explanation. However, the OP is asking if it is possible to get such behaviour without any temporary file. Is it? My tests were unsuccessful.

Comment: By replacing `head` with `sh -c "read line; echo "$line"'`, the desired behavior can be accomplished without a temporary file.

Comment: +1 That's the exact explanation I was looking for! Since you talked about creating own things, I've been thinking about writing a shell script of my own, with a couple of friends; we're thinking about a somehow functional shell, with pattern matching and all of the very coolest trickstery (: